# How to parse complex SOAP Response in KSOAP2

Tags: android, blackberry, ksoap2

I am getting SOAP response which is a bit complex. The response is like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getDetailResponse xmlns="http://saiserviceapp.com/">
      <getDetailResult>
        <UserDetail>
          <UserID>int</UserID>
          <VehicleID>int</VehicleID>
          <UserName>string</UserName>
          <VehicleNo>string</VehicleNo>
          <ModelID>int</ModelID>
          <VariantID>int</VariantID>
          <Color>string</Color>
          <DOP>dateTime</DOP>
          <InsCompany>string</InsCompany>
          <InsExpire>dateTime</InsExpire>
          <ContactNo>long</ContactNo>
          <DInsExpire>dateTime</DInsExpire>
        </UserDetail>
        <UserDetail>
          <UserID>int</UserID>
          <VehicleID>int</VehicleID>
          <UserName>string</UserName>
          <VehicleNo>string</VehicleNo>
          <ModelID>int</ModelID>
          <VariantID>int</VariantID>
          <Color>string</Color>
          <DOP>dateTime</DOP>
          <InsCompany>string</InsCompany>
          <InsExpire>dateTime</InsExpire>
          <ContactNo>long</ContactNo>
          <DInsExpire>dateTime</DInsExpire>
        </UserDetail>
      </getDetailResult>
    </getDetailResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now to parse it i have written this code:

```
 resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    SoapObject root = (SoapObject) resultRequestSOAP.getProperty(mStrProperty);
    SoapObject childObj[] = new SoapObject[root.getPropertyCount()];
    for(int i = 0; i < root.getPropertyCount(); i++)
    {
        childObj[i] = (SoapObject) root.getProperty("UserDetail");
        vector.addElement(childObj[i].getProperty(3));
    }
```

Here i am getting the root value after converting to string like below:

```
    anyType
{
 UserDetail=
      anyType{
          UserID=10884; 
          VehicleID=507; 
          UserName=ffasdd; 
          VehicleNo=GJGJGJG; 
          ModelID=0; 
          VariantID=0; 
          DOP=0001-01-01T00:00:00; 
          InsExpire=null; 
          ContactNo=8888555522; 
          DInsExpire=0001-01-01T00:00:00; 
          }; 
  UserDetail=
        anyType{
            UserID=10884; 
            VehicleID=508; 
            UserName=ffasdd; 
            VehicleNo=HGHGGHJ; 
            ModelID=0; 
            VariantID=0; 
            DOP=0001-01-01T00:00:00; 
            InsExpire=null; 
            ContactNo=8888555522; 
            DInsExpire=0001-01-01T00:00:00; 
            }; 
}
```

Now from this complex response i want the vehicle numbers and want to store them in vector.
Currently with my above code, i am getting the first set of response multiple times. Means same vehicleNo is added multiple time in the vector.

How can i resolve this Issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue in the below way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < root.getPropertyCount(); i++)
            {
                Object property = root.getProperty(i);
                 if (property instanceof SoapObject)
                   {
                     SoapObject category_list = (SoapObject) property;
                     String strVehNo = category_list.getProperty("VehicleNo").toString();
                     String strVehId = category_list.getProperty("VehicleID").toString();
                     vector.addElement(strVehNo);
                     vector.addElement(strVehId);
                   }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this code will help you.

```
int count = root.getPropertyCount();

for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
{
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();                          
    SoapObject root = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("UserDetail");
    String userID = (root.getPropertyAsString("UserID"));  
    String userName = (root.getPropertyAsString("UserName"));
}
```

Comment: thanks @Roxy...its works for me.
`String Key = (s_deals11.getPropertyAsString("Key"));
 String No = (s_deals11.getPropertyAsString("No"));
 String Name = (s_deals11.getPropertyAsString("Name"));`

i got all values of using your code....thanks

Comment: code works but every time i got only one set value...means repeat only first set object values...can you please provide some solution for it...Thanks

Comment: here my code and response in details...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676538/how-to-use-dynamics-nav-service-anytype-response-in-android-side-with-ntlmtran
if anyone've solution then please help.

Answer (score 0):

`(SoapObject) root.getProperty("UserDetail");` is always the same position of `root`

Comment: Then what I should change in the above code. So that i will get vehicle no.

Comment: You can try `childObj[i] = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) root.getProperty(i)).getProperty("UserDetail");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676538/how-to-use-dynamics-nav-service-anytype-response-in-android-side-with-ntlmtran

can you please provide your **valuable solution** for this.